# Колесі як замінник для слова велосипед

Tags: відмінювання

На словотворі [пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/velosyped) *колесі*, двоїну від *колесо*, як замінник для слова *велосипед*. Але як це слово відмінювати? Не хотілось би, щоб це слово довелось відмінювати з якимось особливими правилами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Згадане](/a/7030/585) порівняннє з *ножицї* — недоречне, бо однина існує як *ножиця*, що є мякою ґрупою та жїночого роду, що геть не покращує становище. Тобто це як радити відмінювати *мак* як *краля* — [немає] *кралі*, тому *макі*. Тут точно не *ножик* → *ножицї*, бо таких переходів з чоловічого твердого іменника немає, тобто тут було би радше [два] *ножика* (*вуса*, *рукава*) чи [*ножики*](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_imennyk)<sup>1</sup>. Дивно, що згадане слово *штани* не засмутило, бо воно якраз від *штаня*. А двоїна до *ножиця* буде *ножици* — за гісторичними і сучасними прикладами, як *земли* проти *землї*, *полици* проти *полицї*.

Одна з причин, чому відповідь треба надавати з авторітетними джерелами, або хоча би трохи краще дослїдити [Вікіпедію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), і таких схвалювати. Пак тут є декотрі завади. Перша і очевидна, немає державного унормування, тому або береш з відповідного дїялекта, тобто вже існують декілька варіяцій, або те, що до смаку.

Щодо *колесо* і друга, що явно є іменником твердої ґрупи ніякого роду. Якщо гісторично, то тут проблемка: слово походе від *коло* в буквальному сенсї, котре згодом стало самостійним — чимось нагадує згадане слово *ножницї*. Наросток *-ес-* досї зберігається в іменниках середнього роду з [підтипом на **-с**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9): *небо → [небеса](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) (небесний), чудо → [чудеса](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) (чудесний), тїло → [тїлеса](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) (тїлесний), слово → [словеса](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) (словесний)* ітд. Тому тут для декотрих може постати питаннє як відмінювати слово: як старе *коло* чи як нове *колесо*. І, так, двоїна від старого *коло* якраз буде *колесї* за прикладом [старого] *слово* → *словесї*, що зараз вже *слові*. І умовно сучасне *колесо* теж мати ме *колесї*, але тоді різниця відмінків: сучасне з старого ладу *колесома* (як *двома*) проти *колесьма* (умовно варіятивне *колесима*<sup>2</sup>), де друге звичніше для вух. Для зразку додаю множину.

| Відмінок | двоїна | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Називний | ко́лесї | колеса |
| Родовий | колесу | коліс |
| Давальний | колесьма, колїсьма | колесам |
| Знахідний | колесї | колеса |
| Орудний | колесьма, колїсьма | колесами, колїсьми |
| Місцевий | колесу | колесах |
| Кличний | колесї | колеса |

Від себе тут додав можливу заміну до *колесьма* — ще звичнїше *колїсьма*, пак звичний орудний якраз [*колїсьми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8), зміни закритого *е* на *ї* — не рїдкісне явище.

---

Записки

1. Щодо закінчень іменників при числівниках *два, дві, обидва, три, чотири*, то іменники чоловічого роду бувають із закінченням назовного відмінку (а не родового): *два си́ни, три брати́, чотири вовки́, обидва стовпи́, чотири вчи́телі, три го́луби* і т. ін. (з таким наголосом у іменниках, як у родовому відмінку однини); іменники жіночого роду тверді можуть мати закінчення **-і** (**-ї**), як і мʼякі, при тім **г к х** перед **-і** змінюються на **з ц с**: *дві кни́зі, три вербі́, дві руці́, чотири му́сі, обидві корові́* і т. ін, хоч із **-и**, надто після **г к х**, звичайніше: *дві кни́ги, чотири бо́чки* тощо (так само завсіди з тим самим наголосом у іменників, як у родовому однини); іменники ніякого роду тверді на **-о** при числівниках *дві, обидві, три, чотири* теж іноді мають закінчення **-і** і теж із зміною **г к х** на **з ц с**: *дві я́блуці, три відрі́, обидві сло́ві* тощо (наголос родового однини), хоч звичайніше *двоє ві́дер, три села́* тощо.
2. Деякі іменники на означення парних понять мають форму двоїни і в орудному відмінку: *бровима* (і *бровами*), *грудима* (і *грудьми*), *дверима*, *очима*, *плечима*, *ушима* (і *вухами*); це стосується й низки числівників: *двома, трьома, чотирма, стома* тощо.

Answer (score 1):

НМСД, посилання на статтю у вікіпедії, яка згадує архаїчні типи множин є помилкою. Архаїзми на то й архаїзми, що ними не користуються, бо від них більше проблем (як-от з відмінюванням), або коли слово більше не потрібне, бо ніхто ним не користується сьогодні, наприклад, [крода](https://www.slangzone.net/word/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

[Unicode CLDR](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#uk) називає 2 основні форми для множини, для кількостех `2-4` і `>= 5`. Такий поділ досить добре вписується в сьогоднішні правила і не потрібно видумувати додаткові винятки. Згідно з такими правилами:

- 1 колесо
- 2-4 колеса
- 5 коліс

Але повертаючись до головної теми, щодо `колесі` то тут питання, відмінювати це слово як однину чи як множину? Чи може двоїна вимагає свої, зовсім інші, правила? Правила, які сьогодні існують в українській мові є лише для однини або множини.

Я більше схиляюсь до варіанту трактування двоїни як множини, яка не має форми однини. Можна глянути на іменники, які мають лише форму множини, наприклад: ножиці, штани, окуляри. Провідміняти їх і застосувати ті ж самі правила.

- Н
  -- ножиці
  -- колесі
- Р
  -- ножиць
  -- колесь
- Д
  -- ножицям
  -- колесям
- З
  -- ножиці
  -- колесі
- О
  -- ножицями
  -- колесями
- М
  -- ножицях
  -- колесях
- К
  -- ножиці
  -- колесі

Comment: дякую за виправлення «НМСД», не чув ще такого:)